# Raspberry Pi how to stop running apps with keyboard

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have an app running at startup with a Raspberry pi that takes up display.

I set `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to use static IP, but it doesn't work, it keeps on changing.

So, now I cannot SSH into it, and I cannot check or change the IP manually because I have an app running.

I can plug the keyboard into it, but I can't exit out of the app with keyboard.

I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to reset it, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> doesn't work

How can I stop the currently running app (started with init.d) in the background, so I can at least check the IP.

Bonus question, how can I make sure that the pi has a static IP every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:
    top

This give you all running applications with PID.
Search for PID of this applications and run:

```
sudo kill -9 4444
```

(We supposed that PID =4444)